# How to set clicked <a> tag style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found a menu sample, and want to use it in my site. When mouse enter menu item, its style changes, but when mouse leave menu item, its style is as previous style. User doesn't see which menu item is selected. 
It is css code part:

```
  .navigation ul#topnav li{
        width:auto;
        float:left;
        padding:0;
        position:relative;
    }
    .navigation ul#topnav li a{
        color:#fff;
        background-color:inherit;
        padding:0 7px;
        text-align:center;
        display:block;
        border-left:5px solid transparent !important;
        border-right:5px solid transparent !important;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 50;
    }
    .navigation ul#topnav li a:hover{
        color:#824d97;
        background-color:inherit;
        background:url(../images/nav-hover-bg.png) repeat-x 0 0 !important;
        border-left:5px solid #6c1b93 !important;
        border-right:5px solid #6c1b93 !important;
    }
```

I want when mouse leave menu item after click, its style to be shown as **hover**, and user see which item is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your third CSS selector to something like:

```
.navigation ul#topnav li a:hover, .navigation ul#topnav li a.selected {
```

...so that those settings apply both to the `<a>` being hovered over and any `<a>` with the class "selected". Or if you want the clicked link to have some variation on the hover styles add `.navigation ul#topnav li a.selected {` as a separate entry.

Then in your JS code when a link is clicked you add the "selected" class to it and remove the class from any others:

```
$("#topnav li a").click(function() {
    // whatever else you do on click, then

    $(this).addClass("selected");
    $("#topnav li a").not(this).removeClass("selected");
});
```

EDIT: Place that code in a `$(document).ready()` handler or in a script block at the end of the page.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VFJ7c/

Note: I was assuming (and I think the other answers assumed) that your menu was loading content via Ajax or showing and hiding existing content. If your menu has standard links that reload the entire page then this won't work and you'll need to either apply the "selected" class to the appropriate link in your server-side code or otherwise do it on DOM-ready rather than on click.

Comment: I didn't mention it in my answer, but the JS code I showed should be placed inside a `$(document).ready(function() { /*code here*/ });` handler. With that your CSS plus my suggested CSS change and JS works perfectly here: http://jsfiddle.net/VFJ7c/

Comment: I saw your sample in jsfiddle.net/VFJ7c. I want just that. thanks for it really. All is same in my application. I simply do not understand what is my mistake. May be other .js files prevents it

Comment: What else happens when the menu is clicked? Does the whole page reload, or...?

Comment: yes page reloads, but menu style does not change. hover works. when mouse leave menu, all is as first time.

Comment: As per the note I added to the end of my answer, you'll need to apply the "selected" class either in the server-side code that serves the page for the selected menu item, or in JS on DOM-ready or page-load assuming you can tell at that point which menu item is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

since you're using Jquery you can do the following:

```
$(function(){
    $('.navigation ul#topnav li a').hover(
      function(){
        //remove the active class from all links on mouseover
        $('.navigation ul#topnav li a').removeClass('.active');
      },
      function(){
        //add active class to current link on mouseout
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
    );
});
```

...then add styles for the active class in your css:

```
.navigation ul#topnav li a.active{
  /*your styles*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jquery for this.

```
$('.links').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

And then have a style for clicked links.

```
.clicked{
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a new style for the selected state:

```
    .navigation ul#topnav li a:selected{
     //Your Style Here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to add the another class and add it to the element on click.

JS

```
$('.navigation ul#topnav li a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

CSS

```
.navigation ul#topnav li a.active{
        color:#824d97;
        background-color:inherit;
        background:url(../images/nav-hover-bg.png) repeat-x 0 0 !important;
        border-left:5px solid #6c1b93 !important;
        border-right:5px solid #6c1b93 !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make javascript/jQuery code for it.

OnLoad/ready DOM

jQuery

```
$(".navigation ul#topnav li").click(function() {
     if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
         $(this).removeClass("selected");
     } else {
         $(this).addClass("selected");
     } 
});
```

CSS

```
.navigation ul#topnav li.selected {
    background-color:#selectedcolor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
.navigation ul#topnav li a:visited{ 
    color:#824d97; 
    background-color:inherit; 
    background:url(../images/nav-hover-bg.png) repeat-x 0 0 !important; 
    border-left:5px solid #6c1b93 !important; 
    border-right:5px solid #6c1b93 !important; 
}
```

Comment: Won't that highlight all the menu links that have _ever_ been clicked, as compared to just the currently active (most recently clicked) menu link?